# When params or queries chnage the component does not update

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v5, and react 16

Whenever I navigate like this:

> from "/products/:someId" to "/products/:someOtherId"

the url changes but the components do not update accordingly

it's the same with queries.

> "/products?search=something" or "/products?search=someOtherThing"

it **does work** when I'm in a different url, like "/" or "/users",

[image]

I'm using Link for navigation, I also tried the useHistory hook: history.push, history.replace and withRouter(myComponent);

This is how I'm getting data from queries/params

```
async function searchProducts(searchValue) {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:8000/api/products/search",
    { search: searchValue });
  return response.data.body;
}

const useFetchData = (query) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (products.length === 0) {
      // Use searchProducts for the request
      searchProducts(query).then((foundProducts) => {
        setProducts(foundProducts);
      });
    }
  }, [products, query]);

  return products;
};
```

then I *useFetchData* in my component which goes:

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  // parsing query to be -> { search: "value" }
  const urlQuery = queryString.parse(history.location.search);
  const products = useFetchData(urlQuery.search);

  const getList = () => {
    return products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <ProductItem product={product} />
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  return <div className="container">{getList()}</div>;
};
```

The search button is in a different component for the header, it's always there since it's in the layout

```
<button className="header-search-button" onClick={handleClick}>
  Search
</button>
```

and the handleClick:

```
// searchvalue has it's own onChange handler 
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

// code...

const handleClick = () => {
    // .... some code

    // I also tried with push and Link 
    history.replace(`/products?search=${searchValue}`);
};
```

Comment: Please post the code of how you are getting data depending on params

Comment: I posted some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really difficult to tell without the code.
But my guess is you are able to change the /products?search=bag to /products?search=watch.
But after that it's not able to update the state and hence no re render.When you reload then the render happens.
It would be easier if we could see the code.

Comment: You are not triggering your searchProducts() function when you are doing search.But when you reload the browser it's getting triggered.You are just replacing the value in URL,you also need to trigger the api to get response.
How are you calling the searchProducts() fucntions??can you explain about your components.

Comment: When I press "search"  my ProductList componet uses useFetchData which in turn calls searchProducts

Comment: You are using useEffect() which triggers api call.
Your useeffect has dependencies,so it will be triggered only when dependencies change.Lookslike when you click search these dependencies are not getting changed and hence useEffect doesn't trigger.

Comment: My bad. I  wasn't including a dependency, I thought it wouldn't do any harm, plus the products.length === 0 condition was also a problem since the second time I make the search my product list isn't empty therefore it never calls searchProducts. Thank you for your help :)